# Add keyboard layout in command line in Ubuntu and shortcut to switch

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, keyboard-layout

I want to create a bash script that adds the "French (Canada)" keyboard layout. In addition, I would like to set Alt+Shift as the keys used to change layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `setxkbmap` to change the keyboard layout. For the "French (Canada)" layout, it's `setxkbmap fr-legacy` (I find it with `cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst | grep fr`)

So you can put that in a bash script.

And to add a shortcut, you can add it in Keyboard → Shortcut (in the System configuration board).

Comment: Is there a way to add the shortcut via command-line?

Comment: From [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings) : `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab']"` to make Alt-Tab the shortcut to switch windows for instance. And you will have to edit a file in `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings/` to add your action.